# How to select two columns with different values when the ID matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have 1 table (1) with the users info. A table 2 with users plans. I need to select each users plan and show on the same line in case he's got more than 1 plan.

TABLE 1:

```
+------+------+
|ID    |NAME  |
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|2     |B     |
+------+------+
|3     |C     |
+------+------+
```

TABLE 2:

```
+------+------+
|ID    |PLAN  |
+------+------+
|1     |ASUS  |
+------+------+
|2     |APPLE |
+------+------+
|2     |ASUS  |
+------+------+
|2     |ACER  |
+------+------+
|3     |ACER  |
+------+------+
```

The result should be:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
|ID    |NAME  |PLAN  |PLAN  |PLAN  |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|1     |A     |ASUS  |null  |null  |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|2     |B     |APPLE |ASUS  |ACER  |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|3     |C     |ACER  |null  |null  |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o INNER JOIN para juntar as informações de duas ou mais tabelas (se estiver falando de SQL).

Example:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM 'table1' AS a INNER JOIN 'table2' AS b WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: No [pt.so] seria interessante você responder em português

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua resposta?

Comment: Você pode usar o INNER JOIN para juntar as informações de duas ou mais tabelas (se estiver falando de SQL). Exemplo: SELECT a.*, b.* FROM 'table1' AS a INNER JOIN 'table2' AS b WHERE a.id = b.id;

Comment: Oi Lucas, podes sempre clicar em [edit]. Eu fiz isso desta vez, mas ficas a saber como fazer para a próxima :)